# Multiple android clients and a web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, httpurlconnection, multiple-instances

I have an android client which sends JSON object to the server (REST service).
my client uses urlconnection to connect to the web-service on my server side.

The code works fine!
My server side is a Java class web service using GlassFish server on NetBeans.

Since I'm new to the client-server subject- I have a few questions:

1. How do I test multiple clients on Android Studio? As you know- when I run my client on Android studio- I have only one emulator and 1 program running, But I need to run 2 clients (2 android devices- for 2 players or even more).
2. Do I need to change something on my client side (android) in order to make it possible to multiple clients connecting at the same time?
3. Do I need to change something on my web service app on my server? 
   How do I know if it's safe to handle multiple clients?
   *My server also connects to a data base  (JDBC)

**CLIENT (ANDROID):**
AsyncTask-> doInBackground -> try

```
    try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("string");

    // Step2: Now pass JSON File Data to REST Service
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/w/JSONService");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonObject.toString());
        out.close();

       //string answer from server:
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line="";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                System.out.println("\n"+line);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nError while calling JSON REST Service");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} } }
```

**SERVER (JAVA):**

```
@Path("/w")
public class JSONRESTService {
String returned;
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/JSONService")

public String JSONREST(InputStream incomingData) {
StringBuilder JSONBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        JSONBuilder.append(line);
    }  returned ="transfer was completed";
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
     returned ="error";
}
System.out.println("Data Received: " + JSONBuilder.toString());


return (returned);
 }
 }
```